# Do you need comma after phrases like "Under X ..." or "On the X side ..."?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Example sentence:

> Under an advertisement screen (,) stood a Gothic Lolita. On her left(,)
>   knelt a sweet Lolita.

An ESL teacher told me to remove these commas. But at the same time, they seem grammatical to me. I could be wrong.

Comment: You only use comma's if that subordinate sentence (part) is non-essential, i.e. can be left out. That is not the case here, your sentences would be nonsense without those first parts. The commas are definitely incorrect. This is not an English language issue only.

Comment: @JanDoggen Oh I get it now. So it wouldn't be essential in this case: "Across the street, I sighted a the man."

Answer (score 1):

These commas should be removed. As Jan pointed out, you set off an introductory phrase like this with commas *only when it is non-essential.*  There is a mess of other rules regarding whether you separate it if it is non-essential, but this case is simple. Since the removal of the phrase results in a clearly invalid sentence:

> Stood a Gothic Lolita.

The phrase is essential and should not be separated with commas. 
Likewise the second sentence:

> Knelt a sweet Lolita

Is also invalid without the opening phrase.